# Multiple libraries were found for "wire"\\\\\\\\

Tags: arduino-esp8266

```
Arduino: 1.8.11 (Windows Store 1.8.28.0) (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled (new can abort), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp: In function 'void wiresend(uint8_t)':

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:53:15: error: 'Wire1' was not declared in this scope

  #define WIRE Wire1

               ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:78:5: note: in expansion of macro 'WIRE'

     WIRE.write((uint8_t)x);

     ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp: In function 'uint8_t wirerecv()':

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:53:15: error: 'Wire1' was not declared in this scope

  #define WIRE Wire1

               ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:92:12: note: in expansion of macro 'WIRE'

     return WIRE.read();

            ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp: In member function 'void Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C::begin()':

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:53:15: error: 'Wire1' was not declared in this scope

  #define WIRE Wire1

               ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:120:3: note: in expansion of macro 'WIRE'

   WIRE.begin();

   ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp: In member function 'void Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C::wirereaddata(uint8_t*, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:53:15: error: 'Wire1' was not declared in this scope

  #define WIRE Wire1

               ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:981:3: note: in expansion of macro 'WIRE'

   WIRE.requestFrom((uint8_t)PN532_I2C_ADDRESS, (uint8_t)(n+2));

   ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp: In member function 'void Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C::wiresendcommand(uint8_t*, uint8_t)':

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:53:15: error: 'Wire1' was not declared in this scope

  #define WIRE Wire1

               ^

C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C-master\Adafruit_NFCShield_I2C.cpp:1021:3: note: in expansion of macro 'WIRE'

   WIRE.beginTransmission(PN532_I2C_ADDRESS);

   ^

Multiple libraries were found for "Wire.h"
 Used: C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Wire
 Not used: C:\Users\user\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\Wire
Multiple libraries were found for "SPI.h"
 Used: C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SPI
 Not used: C:\Users\user\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\SPI
Multiple libraries were found for "ESP8266WiFi.h"
 Used: C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\ESP8266WiFi
 Not used: C:\Users\user\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.6.3\libraries\ESP8266WiFi
exit status 1
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have SPI and Wire library installed in libraries folder. This libraries are platform dependent and are the correct version is bundled with the boards package for the platform.

The ESP8266WiFi library is bundled with the ESP8266 Arduino boards package. It should not be installed in libraries.

Delete the Wire, SPI library and ESP8266WiFi from C:\Users\user\Documents\Arduino\libraries\

The Arduino builder should prefer the library bundled with boards package, but the version of builder in Arduino IDE 1.8.11 has a bug and selects the wrong library.